# CFtpFileFind::FindFile() fails with Xfinity (Comcast) but not with CenturyLink

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, wininet, cftpfilefind, cinternetsession

I have a Windows MFC C++ app that uses `CFtpFileFind::FindFile()` to read a list of files from a (shared) server and then uses `CFtpConnection::PutFile()` to upload several files. This works when the ISP is CenturyLink but fails when the ISP is Xfinity. I am able to *read* http files using `CInternetSession()` but I cannot read or write using ftp. I can access files using ftp apps like FileZilla with the same credentials and port number.

The following code experiences this problem. The code does not throw exceptions and all of the pointers look valid regardless of the ISP, but it fails as mentioned in the comments when the ISP is Xfinity.

```
CInternetSession* pSession = nullptr;
try
{
    CInternetSession* pSession = new CInternetSession(DOWNLOAD_SESSION_NAME, 1UL, 0UL, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE);
    CFtpConnection* pConnect = pSession->GetFtpConnection(L"my_ftp_url.com", L"my_username", L"my_password", 21);
    CFtpFileFind finder(pConnect);
    BOOL bFoundFile = finder.FindFile(_T("*")); // This returns false with Xfinity.
    int iFileCount = 0;
    while(bFoundFile)
    {
        bFoundFile = finder.FindNextFile();
        iFileCount++;
    }
    TRACE(L"Found %d files.", iFileCount); // This returns 0 with Xfinity.

    if(iFileCount > 0)
    {
        if(!pConnect->PutFile(L"C:\\test.txt", L"test.txt"))
        {
            const int iError = GetLastError(); // This returns 12003 with Xfinity.
        }
    }
}
catch(CException* e)
{
    // Exceptions are not thrown.
}
```

Ideas? The code was working fine before we changed ISPs.

Thanks!

Comment: FTP ports could be blocked.

Comment: Post FileZilla log file.

Comment: As mentioned in my post, FileZilla *is* able to access the server using port 21, so it doesn't seem possible that port 21 is blocked or that a log file will provide any assistance, although I can post if it'd help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use ftp **passive** mode. Passing `true` for the `bPassive` parameter in the call to `GetFtpConnection()` as shown here allowed ftp-ing using both CenturyLink and Xfinity:

```
pSession->GetFtpConnection(L"my_ftp_url.com", L"my_username", L"my_password", 21, true);
```

If you are calling `InternetConnect()` rather than using MFC, add the `INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE` flag as shown here:

```
InternetConnect(hInternet, L"my_ftp_url.com", INTERNET_DEFAULT_FTP_PORT, L"my_username", L"my_password", INTERNET_SERVICE_FTP, INTERNET_FLAG_PASSIVE, 0);
```

Also, FWIW, when I wasn't using passive mode `GetLastError()` was returning `12003` as the error code.

Comment: From : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-errors

ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR

12003

An extended error was returned from the server. This is typically a string or buffer containing a verbose error message. Call InternetGetLastResponseInfo to retrieve the error text.